# I was given to implement this function: name operator + (name const &) using operator+() in below program

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class name
{
    int x,y;
public:     
    name(int a, int b)  { x=a; y=b; }   
    name operator + (name const &obj){
        name one;
        one.x = x + obj.x;
        one.y = y + obj.y;
        return res;
    }
void print(){
        cout<<"Values are: "<<x<<","<<y<<endl;} 
};

int main()
{
    name c1(4,4),c2(6,6);
    name c3=c1+c2;
    c3.print();
    return 0;
}
```

This displays error: [Error] no matching function for call to 'name::name()'

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: calss ```name``` doesn't have default constructor because when you implement at least one constructor default constructor won't be generated automatically. add ```name() = default;``` or ```int x = 0, y = 0;```. also you should replace ```return res``` to ```return one```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the default constructor, thus one of the working solution might be

```
name operator + (name const &obj){
    name res(x + obj.x, y + obj.y);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @Eljay: My bad.